# Program Doesn't Finish Whole Script

Tags: syntax, python-3.6

I am starting a program in which you have to pick a mode, operation, and then it will calculate it for you. It is still a work in progress.

However, I am running into a problem where it works if you input "A" or "B", and it also works when you input the "sign" or operation. However after the user inputs a sign it finishes the program and exits the code.

I need some feedback on this situation:

My end goal is for the program to also ask the user for input of the numbers they want to calculate, but the program doesn't ask the user for their input. I feel as if this problem has to deal with the float (inputs, `elif`s'(if then else), or how it is stuck in the parameters of the function.

```
 import fractions
print("Welcome to Advanced Calculator Version 1.01")
module = input("Enter a mode, for example; 1NUMBER_OPERATIONS [A], or 2NUMBER_OPERATIONS [B]")
if module == "A":
    operation = input('Enter an operation, for example; sq_rt,fraction,percent,round')
elif module == "B":
    operation = input('Enter an operation, for example; -,+,*,/,^')


def doublecheck():
#OPERATION|||MODESA
    if operation == "-":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 - num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "+":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 + num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "*":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 * num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "/":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 / num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "^":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1^num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "sq_rt":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num_sqrt = num1 ** 0.5
        print('The square root of %0.3f is %0.3f' % (num1,num_sqrt))
    elif operation == "fraction":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        str(fractions.Fraction(num1))
    elif operation == "percent":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        v = 100
        percent= num1 * v
        print(percent + "%")
    elif operation == "round":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        round(num1)
return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function too. Check the last line. Also indent your return 0 statement.

```
import fractions
print("Welcome to Advanced Calculator Version 1.01")
module = input("Enter a mode, for example; 1NUMBER_OPERATIONS [A], or 2NUMBER_OPERATIONS [B]")
if module == "A":
    operation = input('Enter an operation, for example; sq_rt,fraction,percent,round')
elif module == "B":
    operation = input('Enter an operation, for example; -,+,*,/,^')


def doublecheck():
#OPERATION|||MODESA
    if operation == "-":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 - num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "+":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 + num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "*":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 * num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "/":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1 / num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "^":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
        result= num1^num2
        print(result)
    elif operation == "sq_rt":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        num_sqrt = num1 ** 0.5
        print('The square root of %0.3f is %0.3f' % (num1,num_sqrt))
    elif operation == "fraction":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        str(fractions.Fraction(num1))
    elif operation == "percent":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        v = 100
        percent= num1 * v
        print(percent + "%")
    elif operation == "round":
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        round(num1)
    return 0

doublecheck()
```